# elasticsearch 'or' relation between query and filter

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm building news feed functionality for users, I want to process  results with **query** and **filter** too, but I want **'or'** relationship between query and filter terms, 
something like:

```
posts query: 'old castles' or filter: {country: 'France'}
```

which means give me posts where content is searched with 'old castles' term **or** field country is exactly equal to 'France'

P.S.
App is on Rails and I use [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem for elasticsearch interactions

**EDIT**

In elasticsearch reference I found [A Query as a Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_combining_queries_with_filters.html#_a_query_as_a_filter) feature which could be helpful to achieve result I need, but I couldn't find way to do this in **searchkick**

Comment: `{"query":
 {"filtered":
  {"query":
   {"dis_max":
    {
     "queries":
      [
        {"match":
        {"_all":{"query":"castle old","operator":"or","boost":1,"analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}
        }
      ]
    }
   },
   "filter":
    {"and":
     [{"or":
      [{"and": [{"term":{"country":"georgia"}}]},
       {"and":[{"term":{"country":"ukraine"}}]}]
      }]
    }
  }
 },
 "size":24,
 "from":0
}`

sent from searchkick to elasticsearch but it doesn't provide **or** relationship between query and filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use searchkick 'search' method

```
Model.search "old castles", where: { country: 'France' }
```

Comment: This is **'and'** - not **'or'** - relation between query and filter,
it will give me results queried with "old castles" **and** filtered where country is 'France', I need results queried with "old castles" **or** filtered with 'France'